# toggle effect with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a switcher with react that when I click it it change the price of another component and when I click again over it return the original price.

My first approach was this:

1. I crated the input with the type of a checkbox so when `checked` is `true` change the price and when is `false` return the original price, some kind of toggle all handled with the funcion `handleDiscount`

   ```
    <input
      checked={toggle}
      onChange={handleDiscount}
      type="checkbox"
      className="switch-input"
    />
   ```
2. I created the `handleDiscount` function that change the `toggle` from his initial state which is `false` to `true` and and after that a ternary operator that check the condition to set the price.

   ```
    const handleDiscount = () => {
      setToggle(!toggle);
      toggle === true ? setPrice(10) : setPrice(20);
    };
   ```

the problem is that when is click over the checkbox again the price don't change.

I have to work with the `useEffect` hook? which it's the best approach for this kind of work?

for example I wrote the same code with my knowledge in vanilaJS and work, here is the example:

```
const switcher = document.querySelector("input");

switcher.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const priceBasic = document.querySelector(".priceBasic");
  const pricePro = document.querySelector(".pricePro");
  const priceMaster = document.querySelector(".priceMaster");
  if (switcher.checked == true) {
    priceBasic.innerHTML = `<h1>$49.99</h1>`;
    pricePro.innerHTML = "$69.99";
    priceMaster.innerHTML = "$89.99";
  } else {
    priceBasic.innerHTML = "$19.99";
    pricePro.innerHTML = "$24.99";
    priceMaster.innerHTML = "$39.99";
  }
});
```

Comment: Well, you can either use an `useEffect` hook to respond to the `toggle` state changing to update the price, or you can skip the toggle state and simply toggle the price in the handler based on the checked value.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The main issue here is that state updates are asynchronous, the `toggle` value isn't the updated value you just enqueued.

```
const handleDiscount = () => {
  setToggle(!toggle);
  toggle === true ? setPrice(10) : setPrice(20);
};
```

## Solution

Use an `useEffect` to toggle the `price` state when the `toggle` state updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setPrice(toggle ? 10 : 20);
}, [toggle]);

...

const handleDiscount = () => {
  setToggle(toggle => !toggle);
};
```

Alternatively you can make the checkbox uncontrolled and directly set the price state when the checkbox value updates

```
const handleDiscount = (e) => {
  const { checked } = e.target;
  setPrice(checked ? 10 : 20);
};

...

<input
  onChange={handleDiscount}
  type="checkbox"
  className="switch-input"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `toggle` is a state variable and `setToggle` is s state function, in which case, this won't work:

```
  const handleDiscount = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
    toggle === true ? setPrice(10) : setPrice(20);
  };
```

As setToggle is asynchronous. So `toggle` does not actually toggle by the time it reaches `toggle === true ? setPrice(10) : setPrice(20);`

You should instead use `useEffect` and listen to the change of `toggle` like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
   toggle === true ? setPrice(10) : setPrice(20);
},[toggle])
```

And get rid of `toggle === true ? setPrice(10) : setPrice(20);` inside `handleDiscount` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

@codemonkey's answer is correct but if you want something a little simpler:

```js
function YourComponent() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(20);
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const handleDiscount = () => {
    const newValue = !toggle;

    setToggle(newValue);
    setPrice(newValue ? 10 : 20);
  }

  // ...
}
```

Or if `price` is only computed based on `toggle`:

```js
function YourComponent() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const price = useMemo(
    () => toggle ? 10 : 20,
    [toggle]
  );

  const handleDiscount = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While your specific question of getting the toggle to work has been answered, your example in vanilla javascript hasn't been addressed.

Ideally you wouldn't be hard coding different price options directly into the component, but would be serving an array of products which each held their own specific details including pricing options.

There are various ways of handling this, but in the snippet below your `toggle` has become a pointer stored in state in individual `Product` components that can be used to access the appropriate price property of the product object passed to that component. eg.

```
let product = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Product One',
  defaultPricePoint: 'red',
  pricePoints: {
    red: "$49.99",
    blue: "$69.99",
  }
};

const [pricePoint, setPricePoint] = useState('red'); 

let price = product.pricePoints[pricePoint];
// "$49.99"
```

The change handler simply sets the `pricePoint` state using the value of the input that changed (which were mapped from the keys of the object's prices to begin with). And a `useEffect` is implemented to set the initial radio selection based on a default set in the product object.

The result is two fairly simple components and decent separation between data and logic.

(note the use of `key` values that are unique for each mapped element, and not index values)

```js
const App = ({ products }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map(product =>
        <Product key={product.id} product={product} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  const [pricePoint, setPricePoint] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setPricePoint(product.defaultPricePoint)
  }, [product]);

  const handlePricePoint = (e) => {
    setPricePoint(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{product.name}</h3>
      <p>{product.pricePoints[pricePoint]}</p>
      <form>
        {Object.keys(product.pricePoints).map(p =>
          <div key={product.id + p}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="price-point"
              value={p}
              onChange={handlePricePoint}
              checked={pricePoint === p}
            />
            <label for={p}>{p}</label>
          </div>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App products={products} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script>
  const products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Product One',
      defaultPricePoint: 'red',
      pricePoints: {
        red: "$49.99",
        blue: "$69.99",
      }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Product Two',
      defaultPricePoint: 'pro',
      pricePoints: {
        basic: "$19.99",
        pro: "$24.99",
        master: "$39.99",
      }
    }
  ]
</script>

<div id="root"></div>
```